# how to control a figure/model to move in real time

Tags: python

good day sirs. i have a small program that reads and processes data via serial port. these data represent an airplane/vehicle's attitude/tilt. can you suggest any python libraries that will enable me to create graphics that will take the said input and move/tilt accordingly? the simpler the library, the better. forgive me im still a python noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VPython](http://vpython.org/index.html) is the perfect tool for this.  It's super quick and easy to make small 3D interactive moving scenes.  For example, you could easily plot an arrow or two, and update them continuously with your data.

(Of course, use [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/), for reading from the serial port...)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! this site is the best! ill take a look at it sir.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck with it and it sounds like a fun project.  VPython is very quick and easy.  It is intended, btw, for for simple graphics made of a few primitives, and not full video game-type scenes.